# Do not load empty string for decimal field

Tags: mysql, load

Create the table `num` with:

```
CREATE TABLE `num` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `adsh` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `tag` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `version` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `coreg` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ddate` date NOT NULL,
  `qtrs` decimal(8,0) NOT NULL,
  `uom` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `value` decimal(28,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `footnote` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

The data to be loaded:

```
cat  /tmp/num.txt
adsh    tag version coreg   ddate   qtrs    uom value   footnote
0001104659-20-111952    AccountsPayableAndAccruedLiabilitiesCurrent us-gaap/2019        20200630    0   USD 122946000.0000  
0001104659-20-111952    AccountsPayableAndAccruedLiabilitiesCurrent us-gaap/2019    DiamondEagleAcquisition 20200331    0   USD 1495374.0000    
0001640334-20-002456    AccountsPayableAndAccruedLiabilitiesCurrent us-gaap/2019        20190630    0   USD 28710.0000  
0001640334-20-002458    AccountsPayableAndAccruedLiabilitiesCurrent us-gaap/2019        20190930    0   USD
```

To make it more clearly,open it in `vim` and `set list`:

[image]

Without setting `sql_mode =''` to load data :

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'num.txt'  
INTO TABLE num  
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'  
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
IGNORE 1 ROWS 
(adsh,tag,version,coreg,ddate,qtrs,uom,value,footnote);
```

It encounter error info:

```
ERROR 1366 (22007): Incorrect decimal value: '' for column `us`.`num`.`value` at row 4
```

With setting `sql_mode = ''` to load data :

```
SET SESSION sql_mode = '';

LOAD DATA INFILE 'num.txt'  
INTO TABLE num  
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'  
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
IGNORE 1 ROWS 
(adsh,tag,version,coreg,ddate,qtrs,uom,value,footnote);
```

Check the loaded data with:

```
select * from num;
+----+----------------------+---------------------------------------------+--------------+-------------------------+------------+------+-----+----------------+----------+
| id | adsh                 | tag                                         | version      | coreg                   | ddate      | qtrs | uom | value          | footnote |
+----+----------------------+---------------------------------------------+--------------+-------------------------+------------+------+-----+----------------+----------+
|  1 | 0001104659-20-111952 | AccountsPayableAndAccruedLiabilitiesCurrent | us-gaap/2019 |                         | 2020-06-30 |    0 | USD | 122946000.0000 |          |
|  2 | 0001104659-20-111952 | AccountsPayableAndAccruedLiabilitiesCurrent | us-gaap/2019 | DiamondEagleAcquisition | 2020-03-31 |    0 | USD |   1495374.0000 |          |
|  3 | 0001640334-20-002456 | AccountsPayableAndAccruedLiabilitiesCurrent | us-gaap/2019 |                         | 2019-06-30 |    0 | USD |     28710.0000 |          |
|  4 | 0001640334-20-002458 | AccountsPayableAndAccruedLiabilitiesCurrent | us-gaap/2019 |                         | 2019-09-30 |    0 | USD |         0.0000 |          |
+----+----------------------+---------------------------------------------+--------------+-------------------------+------------+------+-----+----------------+----------+
4 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

The field `value` for the 4th line is a empty string ,it was converted into `0.0000`,the field `value` is null and type is decimal by default in table `num`'s definition.
I don't want to load the value as `0.0000` when its value is empty string in raw data file `num.txt`,that is to say ,i expect to load data into following :

```
select * from num;
+----+----------------------+---------------------------------------------+--------------+-------------------------+------------+------+-----+----------------+----------+
| id | adsh                 | tag                                         | version      | coreg                   | ddate      | qtrs | uom | value          | footnote |
+----+----------------------+---------------------------------------------+--------------+-------------------------+------------+------+-----+----------------+----------+
|  1 | 0001104659-20-111952 | AccountsPayableAndAccruedLiabilitiesCurrent | us-gaap/2019 |                         | 2020-06-30 |    0 | USD | 122946000.0000 |          |
|  2 | 0001104659-20-111952 | AccountsPayableAndAccruedLiabilitiesCurrent | us-gaap/2019 | DiamondEagleAcquisition | 2020-03-31 |    0 | USD |   1495374.0000 |          |
|  3 | 0001640334-20-002456 | AccountsPayableAndAccruedLiabilitiesCurrent | us-gaap/2019 |                         | 2019-06-30 |    0 | USD |     28710.0000 |          |
|  4 | 0001640334-20-002458 | AccountsPayableAndAccruedLiabilitiesCurrent | us-gaap/2019 |                         | 2019-09-30 |    0 | USD |                |          |
+----+----------------------+---------------------------------------------+--------------+-------------------------+------------+------+-----+----------------+----------+
4 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

Rewrite load command according to `Barmar`'s idea ,it can't load data with or without setting `sql_mode = ''` .
How to write load statement to get my desired result then?

Answer (score 0):

Use a user-variable so you can test the value from the file and assign an alternate value to the column. In this case, you can use `NULLIF()` to assign `NULL` if it's an empty string.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'num.txt'  
INTO TABLE num  
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'  
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
IGNORE 1 ROWS 
(adsh,tag,version,coreg,ddate,qtrs,uom,@value,footnote)
SET value = NULLIF(@value, '')
```

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'value = NULLIF(@value, '')' at line 7

Comment: Sorry, forgot the `SET` keyword

Comment: And i found that it is no use to not  add `SET SESSION sql_mode = '';`.